# How to create a list of check boxes dynamically depending on another dynamically created select list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, checkbox

I am creating  select lists with different time intervals (8 AM-5 PM, 9 AM- 5 PM etc) dynamically basing on the number of  dates from datepicker. Now, i want to create a list of checkboxes like 8 - 8:30, 8:30-9:00 depending on the option selected from the dynamically created select list. My code is below. Plz let me know why my code is not working.. and give me the correct code.

```
function OptionChange(ddl1,checkList1){
    var content = document.createElement("div");
    var checkList = document.createElement("tr");
    checkList.innerHTML = "";
        var times8_5 = new Array('8:00 AM - 8:30 AM', '8:30 AM - 9:00 AM', '9:00 AM - 9:30 AM', '9:30 AM - 10:00 AM', '10:00 AM - 10:30 AM'
                                 ,'10:30 AM - 11:00 AM', '11:00 AM - 11:30 AM', '11:30 AM - 12:00 PM','12:00 PM - 12:30 PM','12:30 PM - 1:00 PM'
                                 ,'1:00 PM - 1:30 PM','1:30 PM - 2:00 PM', '2:00 PM - 2:30 PM', '2:30 PM - 3:00 PM','3:00 PM - 3:30 PM','3:30 PM - 4:00 PM', '4:00 PM - 4:30 PM'
                                 ,'4:30 PM - 5:00 PM');
switch (ddl1.value) {
            case '8:00 AM - 5:00 PM':
            for(i=0;i<times8_5.length;i++){
                var j=i+1;
                var label= document.createElement("label");
                var description = document.createTextNode(times8_5[i]);
                var checkbox = document.createElement("input");

                checkbox.type = "checkbox";    // make the element a checkbox
                checkbox.name = "times8_5_"+j;      // give it a name we can check on the server side
                checkbox.value = times8_5[i];         // make its value "pair"

                label.appendChild(checkbox);   // add the box to the element
                label.appendChild(description);// add the description to the element

                // add the label element to your div
                checkList.appendChild(label);

            }
            content.appendChild(checkList);
            checkList1.appendChild(content);
           // document.getElementById(checkList2).appendChild(checkList1);
            break;
            }

}

I am calling the above function from the below function xyz

function xyz( number){

    var divElement = document.getElementById("selectList");
    divElement.innerHTML ="";
    var content=document.createElement("div");

     for(i=1;i<=number;i++){
                                  var newDiv = document.createElement("tr");
                                   var text = "Select Time slot";
                                     var select = document.createElement("select");
                                     select.setAttribute("name", "Select" + i);
                                     select.setAttribute("id", "Select" + i);
                                     select.style.width = "300px";

                                     var option_empty;
                                     option_empty = document.createElement("option");
                                  option_empty.setAttribute("value", "Select Time Slot");
                                   option_empty.innerHTML = "Select Time Slot";
                                    select.appendChild(option_empty); 
                                    /* var selectHTML = "Select time Slot";
                                   selectHTML +="<select name='Select"+i+"'>";
                                  for(i=0; i<choices.length; i=i+1){
                                selectHTML += "<option value='"+choices[i]+"'>"+choices[i]+"</option>";
                               }
                                   selectHTML += "</select>"; */

                                    /* setting an onchange event */
                                   // selectNode.onchange = function() {dbrOptionChange()};

                                    var times8_5 = new Array( '8:00 AM - 5:00 PM', '9:00 AM - 5:00 PM', '10:00 AM - 5:00 PM', '11:00 AM - 5:00 PM','12:00 PM - 5:00 PM'
                                 ,'1:00 PM - 5:00 PM',  '2:00 PM - 5:00 PM','3:00 PM - 5:00 PM', '4:00 PM - 5:00 PM');

                                   for(j=0;j<times8_5.length;j++){

                                    var option;

                                   /* we are going to add two options */
                                  /* create options elements */
                                  option = document.createElement("option");
                                  option.setAttribute("value", times8_5[j]);
                                   option.innerHTML = times8_5[j];

                                   select.appendChild(option);
                                   var selectHTML = text ;
                                   newDiv.innerHTML = selectHTML;                         
                                   newDiv.appendChild(select);

                                  }

                                  content.appendChild(newDiv);
                                }
                                divElement.appendChild(content);
                                schedule_meeting_form.count_of_selects.value = number;
                                //document.getElementById("count_of_selects").childNodes[0].value = number;
                                var checkList1 = document.getElementById("checkList2");
                                checkList1.innerHTML = "";
                                select.onchange = OptionChange(this,checkList1);

}


My partial HTML code is :


<tr><td><div id="selectList"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="checkList2"></div></td></tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _my code is not working_? Any errors in console or something?

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple issues:

1. A `<tr>` needs to go into a `<table>`, not into a `<div>` or you need to just create a `<div>` container instead of a `<tr>` if you aren't actually intending to use a table.
2. After creating the new content, you need to insert it into the page.  I only see where you've created a bunch of stand-alone new content, but not inserted it into the actual page.
3. If you intend for the parent to be a table, then data in a `<tr>` needs to be in a `<td>` and you are inserting the checkbox directly into the `<tr>`.

Your code is trying to create this HTML which is not valid:

```
<div>
    <tr>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="times8_5_1">
        </label>
    </tr>
</div>
```

If you don't intend to use a table, then it should be this instead:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="times8_5_1">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you show the before and after for your HTML (what it looks like initially and what it looks like after you've added the checkbox), then we could advise more specifically on the best code for that.

Comment: +1, and also can't modify the innerHTML of a TR in IE, so not a good strategy.

Comment: checkList1 is a div element created in another function..which appends the list of checkboxes

Comment: @user2330222 - show us what the final HTML should look like (edit your question to add this to the end).

Comment: A list of checkboxes created dynamically basing on the input option from another dynamically created select

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment—where you have:

```
> option = document.createElement("option");
> option.setAttribute("value", times8_5[j]);
> option.innerHTML = times8_5[j];
```

you should not use the innerHTML property since the content of an option element is not markup. You can do:

```
option = new Option(times8_5[j], times8_5[j]);
```

or if you want to use *createElement*:

```
option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = times8_5[j];
option.text = times8_5[j];
```

or you can just set the text if the value and text are the same.